# WCF & Rest & ISA & Output

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

I got two questions, but I think that there linked in someways.

I made an WCF Rest service, with .NET4, and only on https. On my local pc, everything is ok.

Now I deployed it to a hosting provider. For what I know all the requests go through an ISA server.

At first, it didn't worked. I tried a lot, but I always got the error 404, resource not found. The specific error is :

```
[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at
&#39;http://mydomainname/items/help&#39;.
This is often caused by an incorrect address URI.
Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches
an address on which a service is listening.
```

First thing I saw is that the URL in the exception is not https. OK, strange, because my web.config is :

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="myNamespace.APIKeyAuthorization, myNamespace" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
...
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
...
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
```

So I tried a lot of things but at the end I made it works. I just put a name everywhere. In the behavior tag, the binding and standardendpoint tag. IT WORKS !!
OK, almost.
Now all my results are in XML format. I got no json. Even with fiddler with the line "Accept: application/json" or "Accept: text/json" it always in XML. Even if I put the automaticFormatSelectionEnabled to false.
And adding the "Help" to the URL, like "https://mydomainname/items/help" I got a "Endpoint not found"

So, now I'm lost, as I don't understand all the tiny configuration in WCF to make everything work.
Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Comment: For what I understand (for now), I'm pretty sure that the name of the standardendpoint *must* be empty to get a functional REST service. I feel stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know if it can be considered as the good answer but admin made something on ISA server.
So now it's fully working.

M.